# Django inconsistency of using tuple and list

Tags: django, list, tuples

Hi I am not sure if this has been asked before, I always gets mixed up using tuples and lists for defining stuff in django framework, eg. you need to use tuples to define list_display, list_filters in admin.py and use lists to define search_fields & ordering fields.

It's hard to remember these things, is there a reason not to consolidate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you got that idea. Tuples and lists are interchangeable for most purposes in Python, and Django is no exception. Both are valid for all of these uses.

Comment: it's from the django documentation, sometimes they use tuples and sometimes lists

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is since, tuples can not be changed after creation this ensures that there is no dynamic changes on them as is not the case in the list. So, if in any case you want to change the ordering field you can do it dynamically.